# Teradata, generating not null latest email address with corresponding customer id

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am new to Teradata.
I wanted to generate "email address" with corresponding "customer id". If the "customer i.d" has multiple "email addresses" then I will go to "updated date" coulmn and check for the latest update and print the required latest email address. If the updated email address is null then, I will go to the previous date and print the corresponding email address.

I tried with

```
Qualify row_number() over (Partition by customerID order by updatedDate, email desc ) = 1
```

I am getting an null values here

```
Qualify row_number() over (Partition by customerID order by updatedDate, email nulls last) = 1
```

Here I could not get the latest one

Could you please anyone help me anyway. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please give a snapshot of the dataset you have ? @Neelima

Answer (score 0):

If you only want non-null email addresses and, if duplicates remain, the email address with the latest update date, then consider:

```
WHERE email IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY updatedDate DESC NULLS LAST) = 1
```

That will pick the newest non-null email address for each `customerID`